# Sony TV XBR-49X705D (Android TV) connect bluetooth headphones

Tags: headphones, bluetooth-audio, bluetooth-pairing

I want to connect Bluetooth headphones to a TV Sony XBR-49X705D.

The TV has Bluetooth, and I was able to join a keyboard, but when I tried to connect the headphones, it didn't work. Is there a way to make this work? Can I buy a USB adapter to improve this Android TV's Bluetooth capabilities?